# With Symfony2 how can I get the form validator to require at least one of a set of fields?

Tags: symfony

I have a from where you can fill in any combination of your home, cell, or work phone numbers.

How can I get the validator to require that at least one is filled in without requiring any of the fields individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two options:

- [Create a custom validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html),
- Or use the [callback constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html).

Comment: There is no example about making a group of fields with at least one field required.

Comment: It's a simple Boolean logic: if field1 is empty and field2 is empty and field3 is empty then set a error message.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this will help get me in the right direction, but I think the validation constraint is wrong for my question. From what I can tell the validation constraint seems to apply to an individual field where the callback applies to the form (technically the Entity).

Comment: It's possible to define validation constraints that work on the class level. [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) is a good example of that.